# Determine the linear mapping $g$ belonging to matrix $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Determine the linear mapping $g$ belonging to matrix $B$, where
$$
B = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\1 & -1\end{bmatrix}.
$$

I don't understand this task. How could I find the linear map of a matrix?

Comment: I don't understand it, either. You must check that book or your notes. The meaning of "linear map for a matrix" is not a standard one

Comment: sorry i translated it again.

Comment: So B defines a map b: R^n -> R^m for some n and m - which? What is b(x_1,...,x_n)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $v=(x,y)$ a linear mapping with matrix $B$ is

$$w=L(v)=B\cdot \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x\\x-y\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $B$ is considered to be a matrix whose entries are real numbers. Now, if you fix a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then to every linear operator $T : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ you can associate a matrix, and to every $2 \times 2$ matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ you can associate a linear operator. This is done in a natural way as follows.

Suppose $( v_1,v_2 )$ is an ordered basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then, every $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ can be expressed uniquely as $v = c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2$ for some scalars $c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. In particular, if $T$ is a linear operator on $\mathbb{R}^2$, let $T(v_1) = a_{11} v_1 + a_{21} v_2$ and $T(v_2) = a_{12}v_1 + a_{22}v_2$. Then, the matrix associated to $T$ is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{bmatrix}. \tag{1}
$$
This is because if $v \mapsto T(v)$ under the operator $T$, then
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
c_1 \\
c_2
\end{bmatrix} \mapsto
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
c_1 \\
c_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} c_1 + a_{12} c_2 \\
a_{21} c_1 + a_{22} c_2
\end{bmatrix}
.\tag{2}
$$

The process can easily be reversed. Suppose you are given the matrix $(1)$ and you wish to find the linear operator $T$ to which the matrix $(1)$ corresponds to under the ordered basis $(v_1,v_2)$. Then, using $(2)$ you can say that $T$ is the map which sends the vector $$v = c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2$$ to the vector $$(a_{11} c_1 + a_{12} c_2) v_1 + (a_{21} c_1 + a_{22} c_2) v_2.$$

---

Now, just specialize to your scenario, when the matrix $(1)$ is given to be $B$, and the ordered basis is as per your problem requirements (possibly the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ should do).